# Three.js random position from mesh coordonates

Tags: javascript, random, three.js

*I'm really new to three.js,*

I would like to give a simple mesh a random position from another mesh coordinates. Just like that :

[image: example]

I want to little yellow box to randomly positionate above the M letter.*emphasized text*

I tried this

```
var points = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry( geometry, nPoints );
        const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(cube, jaune);
        cube2.position.set(1, 0, 0);
        scene.add(cube2);
```

but it doesn't seems to work. Sorry in advance if it's too obvious ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [`THREE.MathUtils.randFloat()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/MathUtils.randFloat). You basically provide a low/high range, and it'll give you a random number within that range.

I'm guessing by your screenshot that the letter `M` is on the x/z plane, so you'll have to provide a random range for both the x position and z position:

```
let xPos = THREE.MathUtils.randFloat(-10, -8);
let zPos = THREE.MathUtils.randFloat(-2, 2);
cube2.position.set(xPos, 0, zPos);
```

*(I don't know how big the letter `M` is, so I'm just guessing numbers. You'll have to play with the low/high values to get the actual range of where you want your cube to randomly show up)*